# Find a system of connectives which is not complete?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm looking at the ternary connectives (pairwise distincts) and I want to find a system of $128$ ternary connectives which is not complete. The maximum of ternary connectives is $256$.

My idea is to consider the $128$ ternary connectives which are true if the three variables are true. That means that for every formulas written with the $128$ connectives it will be true if all the variables are true.

Does it work ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. (And either that or its De Morgan dual is probably the *intended* solution to the exercise).